# MIT Kerberos renew lifetime does not work

Tags: freebsd, kerberos, truenas, mitkerberos, renew

I am trying to figure out why my tickets only get a renewable life of 0 instead of 7 days as I specified.

I tried setting both the `max_renewable_life` (as indicated in another question) as well as `renew_lifetime` to 7 days (`7d` and `856800`) in my krb5.conf and kdc.conf but that did not work. I've set them under `[realms]`(krb5/kdc) and `[libdefaults]`(krb5) but the daemon seems to ignore this setting.
The `ticket_lifetime` however works.

I ran following commands (unneccesary output redacted):

```
$ kinit -r 20m -l 10m PRINCIPAL
$ klist -f
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04.03.2020 19:18:46  04.03.2020 19:28:44  krbtgt/REALM@REALM
    renew until 04.03.2020 19:18:46, Flags: RIA
```

As you can see the maximum life of the kinit works like a charm but renew won't do a thing.

In my frustration I've set those on the client as well with no luck. I know about the `maxlife` of the principal and set it to 7 days as well but that did also not work for me.

If it helps: I am running FreeBSD (FreeNAS) and compiled the kerberos myself.
Is there some other setting to use or is there maybe a compile time option that I need to set?

Edit 1:

```
$ kadmin                                                                       
kadmin:  getprinc comfix
Principal: comfix@REALM
Expiration date: [never]
Last password change: Mi Mär 04 21:00:00 CET 2020
Password expiration date: [never]
Maximum ticket life: 0 days 10:00:00
Maximum renewable life: 7 days 00:00:00
Last modified: Mi Mär 04 21:02:47 CET 2020 (comfix/admin@REALM)
Last successful authentication: Mi Mär 04 22:14:13 CET 2020
Last failed authentication: [never]
Failed password attempts: 0
Number of keys: 2
Key: vno 1, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Key: vno 1, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
MKey: vno 1
Attributes: REQUIRES_PRE_AUTH DISALLOW_SVR
Policy: [none]
```

Comment: What does `kadmin` have to say about the principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution:**

there are 4 settings (5 to be exact but the 5th is the `kinit -r TIME` parameter itself) where the minimum of all is taken:

1. `krb5.conf`: `REALM = { max_renewable_life = 7d }`
2. `kdc.conf`: `REALM = { max_renewable_life = 7d }`
3. PRINCIPAL@REALM: `Maximum renewable life: 7 days 00:00:00` *[1]
4. krbtgt/REALM@REALM: `Maximum renewable life: 7 days 00:00:00` *[1]

[1] (set via `modprinc -maxrenewlife PRINCIPAL` in kadmin)

I forgot/did not knew about the 4th one. After I set the renewlife everything worked as expected. I figured, that as I created the realm the parameters in `kdc.conf` and `krb5.conf` were not set and Kerberos defaulted to 0 seconds...

Comment: thanks I finally understand what is going on.

Comment: For who isn't familiar with kerberos like I am, my kadmin command was like `kadmin.local -q "modprinc -maxrenewlife TIME PRINCIPAL"` in KDC (once for the PRINCIPAL, again for krbtgt/REALM).